# Is there a way to get warnings/errors when a return value of a specific type is unused?

Tags: scala

Does Scala have some equivalent to Rust's #[must_use] annotation?

I have a type which always needs to have a method called on it after it is returned. There are several methods that return it, and ignoring the return value is always an error. (It makes calling the method that returned it entirely pointless.)

I can't use `-Ywarn-value-discard` because the codebase is full of other ignored returns which are fine. I only want a warning/error when certain types are discarded.

Comment: It's too bad the codebase ignores many values and relies on side effects. But you could enable all warnings and then supply a Reporter that filters for the warnings you want. The API is crude, but filtering on text might work. Example http://stackoverflow.com/a/33243657/1296806

Answer (score 0):

> In 2.11: -Ywarn-unused Warn when local and private vals, vars, defs, and types are unused.

But that's not what exactly helps in your case.
[scala does not warn about unused computation or value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691487/scala-does-not-warn-about-unused-computation-or-value)

--

For me, it's looks like design issue.  Suppose you have `init` and `execute` methods.
`execute` can be invoked only after `init`... You should force user to invoke this `init`  method before `execute`.
It can be lazily invoked in the `execute` or during class construction.
I do not really think about scenarios where you really need such warnings.

Comment: Really? You've never seen any type that would be pointless to compute and then discard? In this case we're using scalaz Kleisli so we can compose database operations and run them in a transaction. It may be a bit overly complicated, but you can't redesign it as simply as "always call `init` immediately before `execute`".